# accessing private memeber of a base class error type

Tags: c++, inheritance, error-handling, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I know that when a class member is private, it means nothing other than that class can access it, and the way to solve it is to define it as protected, but what type of error does it cause, for example:

```
class Derived;
class base{
  public:
  base(int a){};
  private:
    int a; 
};

class Derived: public base {
    public:
    Derived(int a) :base(a){}
    void run(){
        this->a=5; // ** (this line is an error)
    }
};
```

so the question is, is the error caused by line ** a preprocessor error or a compilation error, and why? also what are preprocessor errors?

Answer (score 3):

I never heard the term "preprocessor error" before. However, if you mistype a preprocessor directive, for example:

```
#incld <string>
```

Then you get an error along the line of

```
<source>:1:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #incld; did you mean #include?
    1 | #incld <string>
      |  ^~~~~
      |  include
```

Because the preprocessor cannot process the directive `incld`. Altough an uncommon term, this can be called "preprocessor error", because the error happens while running the preprocessor. Actual compilation didn't start yet.

On the other hand, your code results in the error message:

```
<source>: In member function 'void Derived::run()':
<source>:13:15: error: 'int base::a' is private within this context
   13 |         this->a=5; // ** (this line is an error)
      |               ^
<source>:6:9: note: declared private here
    6 |     int a;
      |         ^
```

This error has nothing to do with the preprocessor. There is nothing to be preprocessed by the preprocessor in your code. Attempting to access a private member outside of the class is an error that comes up during the compilation stage.

Comment: A common preprocessor error is attempting to token concatenate (using `##`) two tokens which cannot be combined into a single token, such as `(` and `<`.